# Is using htmlspecialcharacters and single quotes enough for a login form?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-injection

I have the following code

```
$username=htmlspecialchars($_POST['username'],ENT_QUOTES);
$sql="SELECT * FROM user_account WHERE account_name='".$username."'";
```

Is this vulnerable to sql injection. If so, how could someone manage to bypass this?

Comment: check `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: Switch to PDO or MySQLi. Much better then MySQL and MySQL is gone as of PHP7

Comment: @vicky-gonsalves Thanks, but how is that better than htmlsepcialchars?

Comment: @Matkey Because `htmlspecialchars` is for HTML, not SQL.

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements, it really isn't hard.

Comment: Of course, but I am still unable to come up with any input that would work as an sql injection for the above code. I believe my questions is not about how to fix it but rather as to why it is vulnerable in the first place?

Comment: Here's why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116934/is-htmlspecialchars-enough-to-prevent-an-sql-injection-on-a-variable-enclosed-in

Answer (score 1):

Use `MySQLi` like this

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
$con is your connection
```

Read this as well

1. [SQL Injection Protection - single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863957/sql-injection-protection-single-quotes?rq=1)
2. [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

and [Advantages Of MySQLi over MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171344/advantages-of-mysqli-over-mysql)

Comment: Vote for manual links